# Why was my (upvoted and accepted) answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers, vote-to-delete

My answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62026112/why-is-my-while-loop-iterating-only-once (10K+ only) was voted by 3 users to be deleted.

It is an accepted answer with 8 upvotes which was last active 30 days ago.

Now, 8 upvotes means 8 users thought it was useful. How can just 3 users declare it was not useful?

The 3 users who voted for deletion:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/users/6461462/m - has **17 + 3 score** in 2 different [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tags.
2. https://stackoverflow.com/users/10819573/arvind-kumar-avinash - has **0 score** in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag.
3. https://stackoverflow.com/users/1023911/werner-henze - has **1 score** in the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag.

How are users with no experience in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) (on the site) able to vote to delete my upvoted + accepted answer?

If the answer was not useful, users with experience in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) would have downvoted or voted to delete.

As I understand, only users with experience in the tag should be allowed to vote to delete as they understand the question and the answer better.

---

It is today that I noticed a change in my reputation score and that the answer was deleted. And until today, I did not know it was marked as a duplicate.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/):

> What we want is on the order of 4 or 5 similar-but-not-quite-the-same
> duplicates to cover all possible search terms and common permutations
> of the question. It is also OK for these duplicates to have their own
> answers so people who find them don’t have to click yet again to get
> to a good answer.

I understand why we mark posts as duplicate. I vote to close several posts daily. But I do not believe that we should delete an upvoted and accepted answer.

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: The question was deleted. It's not like just your answer was maliciously deleted and the question remains.

Comment: Would you mind providing a screenshot so that users with <10k reputation also can see exactly what happened?

Comment: Honestly, while we should not go out of our way to delete all duplicates, I don't see this one providing exceptional long-term value, and see no reason this one should be preserved specifically. This already had 2 dupes linked, with probably many more to be found because the mistake was very basic. From your linked blog as well: _Having dozens and dozens of variations of the same question is clearly bad._

Comment: [One of the post marked as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33977659/how-do-i-compare-a-string-and-an-integer-in-python) is also a duplicate. Should we also vote to delete that? In fact my answer has a bit of more information and clarity, tbh.

Comment: The bigger question is, should users be able to vote to delete a question in `python` just because they gained 10K+ rep in `java` and have nothing to do with `python`?

Comment: To be blunt, you really have no grounds to complain. One doesn't need to know much Python to recognize this question is 99% a duplicate. Duplicates get closed, and deleted when they aren't novel. That's the way the site operates, and something you should have considered before answering. Spend your energy more wisely next time.

Comment: I personally don't think that question and answer should be deleted as they could still be useful. The title would need to be edited though to make it easier to find for others with the same issue.

Comment: 3 people marked it as duplicate, but they had little to know experience in the Python language. That seems super strange. If 8 python users think it's useful, but 3 non-python users do not..  hmm.

Comment: Just don't answer questions that are likely to be deleted. In high-traffic tags even a mediocre answer could easily garner 5+ upvotes as newbies tend to go *whoa man this is so cool* on almost everything, so the score doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Well, if the answer is oh so useful, why not adapt and post it under one of the dupes? Surely it'll be useful there as well.

Comment: @HarshalParekh To that bigger question, certainly. Content curation and deletion often do not require extensive subject knowledge. There are way too many subjects and way too few users involved in curation to have it any other way, and we don't have specific moderation rules for specific tags. If we'd want to have it any other way content moderation would fail on anything but the large tags.

Comment: Close votes should be thought the same as edit reviews. If your edit review is not what your area of expertise is, you can pass it to someone else. Close votes should be considered similarly.

Comment: *score is how someone coming to the question can trust how useful the answer is* it used to be. now it's not. that question is a duplicate, you shouldn't have answered in the first place

Comment: @Jonathan - And people do that when dealing with questions that aren't trivial. This is a trivial question, and I've yet to see anyone disprove the validity of the duplicate targets themselves. If the dupe targets are good, the tag score of the people involved in closing is entirely immaterial.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica it'd be cool if the answers could be moved from the duplicate question to the original question.

Comment: Correct answers on easily answerable questions get upvoted for being correct by people who would have otherwise answered them all the time. It's not an indication that people who needed the answer found it helpful. a dupe is a dupe is a dupe

Comment: @Jonathan - They can. Moderators (those with a diamond next to their user handle), can merge questions. But the answers need to be applicable as is, without needing to adapt them much, for the mods to consider doing it.

Comment: The answers to the duplicates provide more information than enough, I don't think it's necessary to move OP's answer to one of them. And OP what can I say, next time you encounter a trivial question, before posting an answer check whether it was asked before.

Comment: I would love to see this happening in the CSS tag more often but unfortunately my delete vote remains lonely ...

Comment: The premise of this question is wrong - one does not necessarily need tag experience to see that a question may as well be deleted. The question is - does this question (and its answers) add something new?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Pop into SOCVR we got delete votes there.

Comment: @Dharman yes I know, I was a big *delete vote* spammer there but I have stopped.

Comment: @TemaniAfif: you would be most welcome back `:-)`.

Comment: @halfer thanks :) maybe one day ;)

Answer (score 17):

You do not need to have any score in Python tag to know Python, be an expert in Python and be able to decide if the question is useful or not. Once you gain a certain reputation it is assumed that you can distinguish which questions have value and which ones can be safely deleted. **It is expected that you use your power responsibly**. Any user with 10k can judge if the question should be deleted or not.

I disagree that questions can be deleted, just because they were marked as duplicates, but in this case, I think the decision was right. The question was closed by 3 users and then deleted by 3 other users. 6 responsible users read the question, considered the answers and still decided that this question does not add any useful information to Stack Overflow's database.

The question should have been immediately hammered when it was asked as a duplicate of [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers) but probably no Python gold-badge holder had the chance to review the question in time before the answers were posted. It only took you 2 minutes to write the answer. If it takes you 2 minutes to write an answer, then it means that there probably is plenty of similar questions already asked.

**I am sorry that you wasted time answering this question but hopefully, this will be a lesson for you to research the question before answering and look for duplicates.**

Comment: @HarshalParekh You can consider this deletion as a *good* signal we sent to you in order to better focus your effort. After all this is only one answer that got deleted and you can still provide more. Simply do it for question that really deserve it.

Comment: in short: such basic python questions in 2020 with lots of answers with a zillion votes annoy highrep users _a lot_. Don't be sad: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936285/why-dont-two-plus-operators-throw-an-error-e-g-1-2/41936327#41936327 was deleted, I had a 60-vote answer on it Coincience: last person to delete was also Werner Henze..

Comment: @HarshalParekh - My own anecdotal experience is that it's true. In my own tag of choice, there are plenty of easy to answer question being posed daily (usually to do with undefined behavior). It takes 2 minutes to answer. And there is usually a duplicate. Only problem is the duplicate takes longer than 2 minutes to find.

Comment: @HarshalParekh *I came here to help beginners* --> so you are probably in the wrong place.  You will for sure find better place to do this where there is no moderation around Q/A

Comment: @HarshalParekh We help beginners in many ways. One way is to actually don't dilute the information. This question already had an answer, why would you waste time writing yet another answer if not for reputation? If you close with the right duplicate this is helping users find their answers too.

Comment: Forgive me, but quitting the site entirely because of *one* deleted answer feels like a bit of an overreaction to me. We can't make you stay, certainly, but we'd prefer if you did.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm missing an in-group Python reference that you mention a german composer?

Comment: @HarshalParekh - Flagging the question as a duplicate would have helped beginner Python programmers.  A question being closed as a duplicate is not a negative action.  You indicate you don't take about the reputation, but the reaction you are having due to a single answer being deleted is extremely confusing.  I have simply been inactive on this public profile.